# iOS transition between two html files on a uiwebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have one webview that fits fullscreen and loads an html file. Then another html file is loaded and I would like to apply transition between those files. Possible? Switch between two views that contains another webview is not an option due to any other reasons. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may insert a `UIWebView` inside a `UIScrollView`. Then when you have to load the new page, you create another `UIWebView` and its `x` will be the `width` of the current `UIWebView`, then `addSubview` the new `UIWebView` to the scrollview, and update the scrollview `contentSize`. Then call the method [scrollRectToVisible:animated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible%3aanimated%3a) of scrollview to the frame of the new web view, this do the transition.
In addition, if you don't want to back to the previous page, you may destroy the previous UIWebview and reset the `contentSize` of the scrollview as it was initially.

Answer (score 0):

How "another html file is loaded"? By events in the first webpage?

If you are writing the html pages you could use [jQuery mobile transition](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html)?

[See here](http://blog.codiqa.com/2012/03/jquery-mobile-is-awesome-part-2-pages-and-transitions/)

Even if you are not writing the html pages you might be able to inject javascript for this.